# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' when importing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

When running my module directly with as a flask app through Docker with Python 3, which installs pandas based on the requirements.txt file, it runs fine.  When I import this module from another app, it doesn't find pandas.  The following is my setup.py file.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name='g_plotter',
    packages=find_packages(),
    #packages=['g_plotter', 'pandas'],
    include_package_data=True,
    """ install_requires=[
        'flask',
    ], """
    install_requires=required,
)
```

Failure at:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Traceback

```
server_1  |   File "./g_server.py", line 21, in <module>
server_1  |     from g_plotter import Gparser
server_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/g_plotter/Gparser.py", line 4, in <module>
server_1  |     import pandas as pd
server_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

In Docker I don't see pandas being installed:

```
Step 12/15 : RUN pip3 install ./g_plotter
 ---> Running in 7cc0957f23e6
Processing ./g_plotter
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from g-plotter==0.0.0) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask->g-plotter==0.0.0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask->g-plotter==0.0.0) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask->g-plotter==0.0.0) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask->g-plotter==0.0.0) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->flask->g-plotter==0.0.0) (1.1.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: g-plotter
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for g-plotter: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for g-plotter: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-iu6t3zln/wheels/a5/fc/d6/bbda9e5e615cade7b93e6d32cfba9062e2b21ea5352d0c2be0
```

Comment: Have you tried installing using a virtualenv so you can see what packages are being installed?

Comment: @Alex, just updated the question with the Docker output.  It looks like it's recognizing the common packages but no pandas.

Comment: You could check that your `required` list is as expected?

Comment: @Alex, it turns out I had two setup.py files, one at the root and one in the submodule's folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had two setup.py files.  One at the root and one in the subdirectory with the rest of the code.  I was updating the inner one. Once I move that up and replaced the old one, all the dependencies got installed.